# I need to develop a WCF service that will only be exposed thru HTTP/HTTPS. How to use HTTP cookies?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http

First of all, I admit I'm a newbie in WCF. Still not out of the training wheels.

I was assigned to develop a WCF service, and part of the requirements is that a sort of "session token" needs to be passed with each request as an HTTP cookie. (Predictably, such token needs be generated in the HTTP response headers of a successful "logon" call in such service).

Is this straightforward?

Comment: Did any of those answers help you?

Comment: I'm sorry, the need for an answer has been deprecated. Requirements have changed and now I can pass things in the objects. What should I do with this question, delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer:  you're not really supposed to do any of this, because it's forcing a WCF service to behave as a web service.  But if you need cookies, read on.*

If all you need is the session id, you can get it from:

```
OperationContext.Current.SessionId
```

If you need cookies, you'll need to jump through some hoops.  The gist of it is (1) set asp.net compatibility, and (2) reference HttpContext.Current properties.

Your service will need to use a wsHttpBinding (or another binding that supports sessions).  If create your project to be a WCF service hosted in IIS, you'll get these by default.  You'll also need to set asp.net compatibility in the config file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="MyBinding" allowCookies="false" ... </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

(see the link [here](http://kennyw.com/work/indigo/211) for why I have allowCookies=false)

To enable sessions, on your WCF Service Contract, set the following

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IMyWcfService {...}
```

You may also want to set the ServiceBehavior on the service itself (PerSession is the default), and you'll need to set asp.net compatibility.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class MyWcfService : IMyWcfService {...}
```

Some relevant properties you then have access to:

```
// Gives you the current session id as a string
HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID  

// Indicates whether the service is using sessionless cookies
HttpContext.Current.Session.CookieMode

// Indicates whether the session id is stored in the url or in an HTTP cookie 
HttpContext.Current.Session.IsCookieless

// The cookies themselves
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies

// The session and cache objects
HttpContext.Current.Cache
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

A link on sessions in WCF Services:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx

HTH,
James

Answer (score 0):

This topic on msdn could help you out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398778.aspx.

Also, this could help you out with hosting you`r WCF service inside IIS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx (Hosting Using Internet Information Services)

Answer (score 0):

This just answers your question partially, but will give you a head start with config. 
In your config file under the service config section, create basic http bindings like that:

```
<system.serviceModel> 
        <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="myHttpBinding" allowCookies="true">

      </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then read up on wcf binding and endpoints configuration.